# Ubuntu 12.04 virtualbox slow

Tags: 12.04, windows, virtualbox

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual Box Manager on Windows 8.1 for ROS. I have been trying to run it so I can communicate with a robot through USB. However, the system runs slow and lags the signal, even though the VM has 2 GB of memory.

My computer has a core i7 4th gen, 8 GB of ram and 1TB HDD. My windows system runs normally, but nothing but Chrome and excel is open on it and the windows side runs fine.

Any ideas about what might be causing this issue? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most BIOS and CPUs now have 'Virtualization Technology' of some sort.  Depending on the manufacturer, this may be called **VT-x**, or **AMD-v**.  You should first determine if these can be enabled within your BIOS, and then, if they were available, enable them within the BIOS and then within your Virtual Machine's settings within VirtualBox.

Another thing that will improve performance is to install the Guest Partitions for VirtualBox.  This should give you better access to hardware, including USB and Graphics Cards, etc.

Also, while 2GB or RAM might be plenty for your VM, you might try increasing it to 4GB, or ensuring proper SWAP is available.  Also, since you're on an i7, you could probably give the VM at least two cores on which to run.

You may want to take a look at [Oracle's Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#ts_usb-linux) covering USB issues, as well as checking *Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller* under USB in the Virtual Machine's settings.

A side note is that I've never run VirtualBox under Windows to run Linux.  I've always used a Linux host with VirtualBox to run Windows.  Linux seems to be better at handling virtualization than Windows, but these suggestions should help you a bit.

Comment: Apparently, my virtualization was off, thanks for the advice! It helped!